# pointer to member: pointer and array element

Tags: c++

Please verify if my understanding about a pointer to member is correct. Here is an example class:

```
class T
{
public:
       int *p;
       int arr[10];
};
```

For "standard" pointers following opartions are common:

```
int a = 1;
int *p1 = &a;
int *p2 = p1 (other notation: int *p2 = &*p1);
//The pointer p2 points to the same memory location as p1.
```

The above operation for a pointer to member is impossible:

```
int T::*pM = &(*T::p); // error
```

A pointer to member contains an offset in the memory i.e. information how far away is placed 
particular member starting from the beggining of the class, so we don't know at this 
stage where a pointer inside the class points. Similary a pointer to member which is an array element is impossible because the address of the array element is unknown:

```
int T::*pM = &T::arr[5]; //error
```

But following operations are correct:

```
int* T::*pM = &T::p; //a pointer to a pointer 
//the same operation for "standard" pointers:
int **p3 = &p2;
int (T::*pM)[10] = &T::arr; //a pointer to an array
```

Comment: I suggest that you ask _one_ question at a time. See the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for more details about asking.

Comment: So what's the question, after all?

Comment: Despite the name, a pointer-to-member is *not* a pointer, and doesn't behave one. It doesn't make sense to talk about "the same operation" for both types, since there are no operations that apply to both. Your errors are from trying to dereference it (you can only dereference pointers), and trying to point something other than a member (since only the array is a member, not its elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that it does not really make sense to use dereference + address of operator in the first place, and it can cause undefined behavior in cases (for example, if the pointer is null). So the first half of the answer is you **shouldn't** in the first place.

The second part of the answer is that a pointer-to-member is **not** a pointer, but a mechanism to access a member given an object. Even if they share the *pointer* word in their names, they are completely different beasts and you cannot dereference a pointer-to-member, not to create a copy, not for any other reason or in any other context.

Regarding a pointer to a member of an array that is stored inside your object, the problem is that that array member is *not* a member of your type, but a member of the array. The problem is not that the location is unknown, it is very well known to the compiler which is the offset of the array from the complete object and which is the offset of the array element within the array, and the compiler does know how to add.

From the last three examples, the first two are just plain simple to explain. Given a type `T` (whatever that is) and an object `t` of that type, you can create a `T*` by taking the address of the object: `&t`. Whether `T` is a class, a pointer, a pointer-to-member, enum... does not matter at all.

Finally the last case is again simple. Given a class C and a member m of type T within that class, you can always create a pointer-to-member that refers to `m` by using the syntax: `T C::*ptr = &C::m;`. Now the grammar for types is complicated in C and C++ and when the type `T` is an array the type *spills* to both sides as in `X (C::*ptr)[5]`, but that is not different than the simpler to read:

```
typedef int int5[5];
int5 T::*pM = &T::arr;
```