# How to build a consolidated view on several member arrays?

Tags: c++, c++11

A member function receives objects which have each two or more members which are arrays (C-style, `T[]`) of the same type. How can one map those arrays of one object into one? Such as a `for`-loop can be used to iterate over the "concatenated" array. The objects have the same classifier. It can not be assumed that the array elements are in a contiguous memory space. The array elements shall not actually be copied or moved.

I thought of using [pointer to data members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members). One can define [pointers to array members](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/641322-c-pointer-to-member-array-of-int/?do=findComment&comment=5050088). According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19818711/5534993):

> it is very well known to the compiler which is the offset of the array from the complete object and which is the offset of the array element within the array, and the compiler does know how to add

For example in the following code I tried to accomplish it for the member function `process()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr size_t As = 3;
constexpr size_t Bs = 2;

struct Parts
{
    char a[As] = { 'A', 'B', 'C'};
    char b[Bs] = { 'D', 'E'};
};

class Processor
{
    void run(const char& o) const { cout << o << endl; }

    ??? abs[As + Bs];

  public:
    Processor()
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        for(; i<As; ++i) abs[i] = &Parts::a[i];
        for(; i<As+Bs; ++i) abs[i] = &Parts::b[i-As];
    }

    void process(const Parts& m) const { for(char& o: m.*abs) run(o); }
};

int main() 
{ 
    Parts m, n;
    Processor p;

    p.process(m);
    p.process(n);

    return 0; 
}
```

The member `abs[]` shall be the continuous representation of the joint arrays `a` and `b`.

Is this even possible? Is there maybe a completely other way to loop over array elements of seperate arrays of one object?

Comment: It is not clear what the real problem is. If `a` and `b` are distinct arrays, obviously, you can't iterate directly over their concatenation as over a contiguous range without making copies. If you want to iterate over `a` and `b` *as if* they were a single array, you can make a custom iterator, something like `std::deque`'s one - when it hits the one past the last element of `a`, it goes to the first element of `b`.

Comment: I fail to see, why it could not be done (as you state in your answer), nor, what this has to do with member pointers. I think there are at least three ways to do this.

Comment: @churill, could you please post an answer sketching possible solutions? I would love to hear about your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be realized because of several reasons.

First of all array elements must be in contiguous memory space.

Also, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674743/5534993):

> accessing an item in an array is another level of indirection from accessing a plain int

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674635/member-pointer-to-array-element#comment56816095_674675): [Defining some kind of double indirection to member data] can not be done with the language.